# Query performance in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, query-performance

What factors should I check when I compare the performance of a query?

I saw many articles stating about IO cost, subtree cost (by using Execution plans), statistics such as CPU time, elapsed time (by using set statistics time on), time required for running query etc.

I have seen some queries which have high subtree cost but execute fast. So I want to know which factors I have to consider while checking performance of a query.

Comment: You can check [SQL-Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp#benefits) which shows actual execution plans.

Comment: The is a very broad topic. Can you be more specific as to what you are trying to do and where you need help ? It is like saying - get me everything I need, without saying what you need !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subtree cost is not a good general indicator. Even in actual plans the costs shown are based on estimates and inaccurate cardinality estimates can occur.

Even if the cardinality estimates are perfect however the costs shown are still just derived from costing formulas which may bear little relation to the true actual performance. Certain constructs such as scalar UDFs are generally woefully undercosted in the plan.

Logical reads can be a very useful indicator but not all logical reads are equal. A read of one row on a page that is already in cache is obviously much cheaper than reading all rows on a page that needs to be brought in from disc. One other issue to be aware of is that logical reads for work tables report **rows** read not **pages** so the units are not always consistent.

Elapsed time is a useful indicator but that requires some interpretation too. When looking at the elapsed time of two queries you might prefer a query with a slightly greater elapsed time that uses less resources (e.g. lower memory grant or serial plan rather than parallel)

Comment: Will probably add some more later but the question may be closed by that point.

Comment: Didn't know that worktables report *rows* as logical reads. Thanks Martin :-)

Comment: @JohnAlan - I didn't know it either until the answer to [Why are logical reads for windowed aggregate functions so high?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5194902/73226)